# Issues with R Script - sampling from a list and using interval

Tags: r, loops, dns

**Hi there, here is my code...**

```
# Load Libraries and Suppress Messages:
#
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))        # Re-arranging data frames
suppressMessages(library(httr))         # For http utilities
#
# Read in the URL Data from CSV:
print("Read the Data into R...")
url_list <- read.csv(file="urllist.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)
#
# Example HTTR Package 'HTTP GET' Code:
# GET("http://symantec.com/")
#
# For' Loop for URL List Iterations
for (i in 1:40) {
  selected_sample <- sample(url_list$V1, size=1, replace=FALSE)
  GET(selected_sample)
  interval <- runif(1, min=1, max=2)
  Sys.sleep(interval)
}
#
# Finish the Script:
print("Finished & Closing Script")
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
[1] "Initializing Script"
[1] "Read the Data into R..."
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name
```

**Here is my explanation:**

I am trying to write a test script that will read from a list of URL's over a period of time (1 hour) and generate DNS requests on my DNS server in the DNS logs. The generation of DNS requests in the DNS logs is working but getting the timing right is proving tricky.

I am having trouble with the "interval <- runif(1, min=1, max=2)" line. I think it should only say 1 for the vector but with 1 it errors, if I use 40 it errors with the same, whilst if I use 3 it doesn't error but I don't understand why?

I am also thinking for approximately 1 hour my FOR loop should be set to loop about 2400 times with an interval of between 1 and 2 seconds?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Rick

Comment: print out each url before GET to make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: The error being a resolution problem in the GET (curl) I don't see why you blame runif ...

Comment: Hi pcantalupo and Tensibai, thanks very much your advice really helped. I think I had a bad url in my list of url's. I replaced it for another and managed to run without errors. Thanks very much, Rick

Comment: I am now going to run a loop with 2200 iterations and time it, hopefully it will be approximately 1 hour with the interval I have added. Thanks Rick.

Comment: 600 iterations took about 1 hour, thanks, all questions now solved.

Answer (score 0):

print out each url before GET to make sure they are what you expect. –  pcantalupo

The error being a resolution problem in the GET (curl) I don't see why you blame runif ... –  Tensibai

Hi pcantalupo and Tensibai, thanks very much your advice really helped. I think I had a bad url in my list of url's. I replaced it for another and managed to run without errors. Thanks very much, Rick –  rick_thompson

600 iterations took about 1 hour, thanks, all questions now solved.